# A string that starts and ends with xt

Tags: java, regex

I have a string: "\nxt9090.33xtxh77.77xhy90y"

How to get:

1. The **9090.33 which starts and ends with xt**
2. The **77.77 which starts and ends with xh**
3. And the **90 which starts and ends with y**.

The string could be large with the same patterns.

I will be using the **split (String RegEx)** of the class String in Java.

Comment: [`(\w+)(.*?)\1`](https://regex101.com/r/g0tpUL/1). Use second captured group string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these separate lookups:

```
1: (?<=xt)[\d\.]*(?=xt)
2: (?<=xh)[\d\.]*(?=xh)
3: [\d\.]*(?=y)
```